Jenkins Pipeline Groovy string Comparison not working
I have been struggling with this for a few hours trying several different things. I started off using a switch/case because the txt.txt file only contains a numeric state [0 .. 4].
The output from the server clearly shows it is a String, so why is it always failing the strcmp test in both conditional statements (if..else, switch/case). This make no sense.
def output = readFile "$WORKSPACE/txt.txt"
println output.getClass()
println output
if (output == "1") { // also tried converting toString() both before and during the if stmt
  println "Jenkins Node diskspace starting to get a bit slim."
}
else {
  println "Plenty of disk space"
}

Yields this result:
10:41:14  [Pipeline] stage
10:41:14  [Pipeline] { (Execute script to get disk usage status)
10:41:14  [Pipeline] script
10:41:14  [Pipeline] {
10:41:15  [Pipeline] readFile
10:41:15  [Pipeline] echo
10:41:15  class java.lang.String
10:41:15  [Pipeline] echo
10:41:15  1
10:41:15  
10:41:15  [Pipeline] echo
10:41:15  Plenty of disk space
10:41:15  [Pipeline] }
10:41:15  [Pipeline] // script
10:41:15  [Pipeline] }
10:41:15  [Pipeline] // stage
10:41:15  [Pipeline] }
10:41:15  
10:41:15  [Pipeline] // ansiColor
10:41:15  [Pipeline] }
10:41:15  [Pipeline] // node
10:41:15  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
10:41:15  Finished: SUCCESS


you have new line symbol in a file. you can try to do if (output.trim() == "1") ...

@daggett That did it. Holy crap that was driving me mad. TYVM!

you have new line symbol in a file.
10:41:15  [Pipeline] echo
10:41:15  1
10:41:15                        <<< an empty line after 1

you can try to do
if (output.trim() == "1") ...

